# Quickly generating random numbers in C#

Tags: c#, random

I'm creating a program which creates several panels with randomly determined colors which will be incremented/decremented by some random constant every 20 milliseconds or so to create a smooth, undulating color.  For this, I've just been using the Next(int) method of the Random class.  For a single instance, this works perfectly--every time I run the program, I get different colors changing at different rates.  The problem comes when I try to create multiple panels--most, if not all, come out looking and behaving identically to each other, implying that all of the randomly generated numbers were identical.  I'm assuming that this is a result of generating all of the pseudorandom numbers in rapid succession, causing all of them to be based on the same seed.

Is there a better way than using the Random class to generate random integers in rapid succession to ensure that they're not identical?  If there isn't any way already built into C#, is there any straightforward way to develop a pseudorandom number generator (bearing in mind that this is my first foray into using C#)?

Comment: Are you re-initializing/recreate a PRNG object each time? A decent PRNG should not reliably produce the same numbers as you describe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use multiple instances of the Random Class using the default constructor. If they all are initialized within the same time slice they will all have the same seed and will all generate the same sequence of random numbers, use the constructor that [you can pass in a seed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww.aspx) and pass a different seed to each instance.

```
Random rand0, rand1, rand2;

void init()
{
      int baseSeed = (int) DateTime.Now.Ticks;
      rand0 = new Random(baseSeed);
      rand1 = new Random(baseSeed + 1);
      rand2 = new Random(baseSeed + 2);
}
```

Also you only need one object per thread, use the same Random object for all of the panels if they are all on the same thread.

Comment: Or, alternately, just create one central instance of Random and use that for all random number generation.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan: Well, one per thread. They're not thread-safe.

Comment: Reusing an existing random number generator is generally a simpler idea than creating a new instance with a seed each time. After all, if you've got to keep the seed around, why not keep the reference to Random instead?

Comment: @JonSkeet I assumed he was re-useing them but was making multiple instances very quickly, I updated my answer for clarification.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: If the `Random` instances *aren't* on the same thread, it needs a little more caution in order to atomically update the seed :) (Why are you restricting the seed to the range 0-65535 though?)

Comment: I was cannibalizing the code from the [example page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww.aspx) for the constructor, I guess it is not needed, I will remove it.

Comment: @JonSkeet what do you mean by "it needs a little more caution in order to atomically update the seed", I made some assumptions but this was written in mind that init() would be called, and returned, before any of the threads that used the random object would start. atomicity should not be a issue as we are still in a single threaded environment during the initialization stage.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Hmm... that would be slightly unusual, IME. I would typically initialize an object on the thread I planned to use it on. That's usually a safer bet, avoiding nasty memory model gotchas etc.

Answer (score 2):

`Random` is fine if you don't need cryptographically secure random numbers - but chances are you're creating a new instance every time you need a number, rather than using *one* instance throughout.

When you create a new instance of `Random` it will take "the current time" as the seed - so if you create two in quick succession, you'll end up with two instances with the same seed and therefore the same numbers (when you use the same calls).

It's generally better to use a single instance of `Random` - or rather, one per thread, as it's not thread-safe.

See my [article on the topic](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx) for various approaches.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`. It is roughly as fast as `Random` and tends to produce more unique values in my informal testing. You also avoid any undesirable behaviors pertaining to seeding (such as others are describing).

However, you can't guarantee uniqueness (otherwise it wouldn't be random). You can use a database if you need to permanently track unique values (which it doesn't sound like you wish to do) or a `Dictionary` where the random value is the key if you just care about generating a set of unique numbers in memory. If the key already exists, you reject the value and generate another one.

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

...

RNGCryptoServiceProvider crypto = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
crypto.GetBytes( bytes );
long value = BitConverter.ToInt64( bytes, 0 );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple instances of the `Random` class that are producing identical series of random numbers, then you must be creating each instance using the same seed. For example:

The most likely explanation for that is that you are creating them all like this:

```
var rng = new Random();
```

and creating each instance at the same point in time. This constructor uses the current time to seed the RNG and if you create them all at the same point in time, they will all be seeded with the same time.

Solve the problem by creating each instance with a different seed. Or create a single RNG and share it between all panels.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you can use a single instance of the random class. However, if for some reason this isn't desirable (i.e. you want to run multiple threads and don't want any contention), then you can use multiple instances as long as you initialize the seed for each generator to a random or pseudo-randomly generated seed.

For this initial seed generation, you will need to use the same Random generator.